# How can I find a link to Guardian's list of postgraduate open days for 2014-15?

Tags: website

The Guardian newspaper website has previously published a list of postgraduate open days at UK universities. However, I cannot see the list of postgraduate open days for 2014-15. Does anyone have the link please?

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling found a Guardian article this summer that now points to a separately established website which seems to aim to be a long-term resource:  http://www.findamasters.com/opendays/